# Unable to find the count(*) of cassandra table throwing consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax, datastax-enterprise, databricks

I have a scenaio to write the data into cassandra table using spark -sql.
I have a 3 node cassandra cluster.
I created table with replication factor 2  as below :

```
CREATE TABLE keyspaceRf2. c_columnar (
    id int,
    company_id int,
    dd date,
    c_code text,
     year int,
     quarter int,
        etc ....etc...
    PRIMARY KEY (( id,  year,  quarter), dd, c_code, company_id )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( dd DESC, c_code DESC, company_id DESC);
```

I am trying to insert the data into keyspaceRf2. c_columnar table using spark-job on the spark-cluster.
 The data being inserted properly.
 But inorder to verify the count of records inserted into table, I am running a count query as below

```
 val countDf = loadFromCassandra(c_reader,"keyspaceRf2", " c_columnar");

println ( " count = " + countDf.count()


def loadFromCassandra( c_reader: DataFrameReader , keyspace: String , col_Name:String): DataFrame = {

        c_reader
        .options(Map( "table" -> col_Name, "keyspace" -> keyspace ))
        .load()
  }
```

When the above code is executed , it is throwing error as below

ERROR :

```
TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 33.0 in stage 18.0 : java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT count(*) FROM "keyspaceRf2"." c_columnar" WHERE token("id", " year", " quarter") > ? AND token("id", " year", " quarter") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:350)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:37)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultScanner.scan(Scanner.scala:34)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:342)
        ... 15 more
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Please double check:

- *The keyspace replication settings* - Replication factor is set on keyspaces, not tables. Make sure you use the correct replication strategy for your cluster topology. Using the default `SimpleStrategy` in a multi-DC cluster will be almost always wrong. Another mistake is using `LOCAL_ONE` instead of `ONE` CL when there is not even a single replica in the local DC. No replicas in local DC may be caused by forgetting or misspelling the DC name in `NetworkTopologyStrategy` options or by using `SimpleStrategy` which may decide to store all replicas for a particular range in another DC.
- *The state of the nodes in the cluster* - A count query may need to access many nodes. Check your cluster health. Check all nodes are in state UN (up, normal).
- *The node you're connecting to is in the right DC* - With multi-DC clusters and LOCAL_* consistency levels, it is extremely important to connect to the right DC.

Comment: thank you for quick reply, 
1) Yes the replication factor is set on keyspaces not on tables.   
2) This cluster which i am using is on single DC   
3) Keyspace follow 'SimpleStrategy' as shown below 

CREATE KEYSPACE keyspaceRf2
WITH durable_writes = true
AND replication = {
 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
 'replication_factor' : 2
};

4) Checked the state of nodes in CL , all are up and running
5) I have only one DC and all nodes/connections connecting the same.

Comment: Quite interestingly I am able to query the data with "select query" but not able to use count(*) query.

Comment: @ Piotr Kołaczkowski  , you mean log level DEBUG ? cassandra side I dont know how to do it .

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html